# how to stop TweenLite and how to repeat a function with TweenLite

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, gsap

So basically I want to make a Blinking effect with a textField where the time will be 1 sec. I have only a "brut" code that I think it can be done easier but coundt figure out how to make it loop.

i have only this

```
private var myBlackText:TextField = new TextField();
    private var myRedText:TextField = new TextField();
    private var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

    public function Main()
    {
        this.addChild(myBlackText)
        myBlackText.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',20,0x000000);
        myBlackText.x = 200
        myBlackText.y = 200
        myBlackText.text = "YOYO"


        this.addChild(myRedText)
        myRedText.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',20,0xFF0000);
        myRedText.x = 200
        myRedText.y = 200
        myRedText.text = "YOYO"

        TweenLite.to( myRedText, 1, { alpha:0, onComplete:ShowRed });
        function ShowRed():void
        {
            TweenLite.to( myRedText, 1, { alpha:1, onComplete:HideRed });
        }
        function HideRed():void
        {
            TweenLite.to( myRedText, 1, { alpha:0, onComplete:ShowRed });
        }
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    private function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //how do I stop the TweenLite ????
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to kill the tween, this is as simple as possible.

```
TweenLite.killTweensOf(myRedText);//will kill all tweens of myRedText
```

Try this if you want it be more simple in just on line.

```
TweenMax.to( myRedText, 1, {alpha:0, repeat:-1, yoyo:true} );
```

Explain:

`repeat=-1` means repeat forever.

`yoyo=true` means do Red's alpha from 1-0 and 0-1

So the whole is Red's alpha from 1-0-1-0-1...

Comment: huh strange how i didnt find this so far.10x, yet any hints how to make the whole thing (the loop effect) more eye-pleasing ? Is there something like a loop function in this Tweenlite

Comment: @GregorII I think the effect is ok, and what you mean by `a loop function`?

Comment: to repeat the wanted effect until there is a click on the stage.
i found this `var myTween:TweenMax = new TweenMax(mc2, 3, {y:200, repeat:2, repeatDelay:1, onComplete:myFunction});` and if i change the **repeat** variable to -1 it repeats this forever but dont know hot to give it 2 alpha variables so it goes from 0 to 1 and then from 1 to 0

Comment: well ... what i found (the above comment) doesnt work.Or atleast i cant make it work.Im doing `TweenLite.to( myRedText, 1, { alpha:0, repeat:-1, repeatDelay:1, onComplete:ShowRed});
   function ShowRed():void
   {
    myRedText.alpha = 1
   }` and it only does it once. And even if i change the **repeat** from -1 to 10 it still does it once.

Comment: exactly what i wanted. 10x